# What's the best practice to validate user access rights in a client-server FMX Delphi application?

Tags: delphi, client-server, firemonkey

After the user is logged, what's the best practice to validate user access rights to all other requests in a client-server FMX Delphi application?

- Validate in the database on every request?
- Embed user permissions in the token generation, so that in every token authentication the server also validates the access rights?
- Create a backend session for every user to store the permissions and validate in every request? (If so, how can does a session is made in delphi?)
- Or any other?

Comment: Ask the user to login using a pre-registered username and password everytime they run the application.

Comment: @FreddieBell - That's not the point. Sorry, probably i wasn't clear in my question. I'm saying after the user is logged. He requests some event, lets say GetEmplyeeList, so the backend will validate if he has the proper rights to access this event.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648275/how-can-i-obtain-the-authenticated-username-and-password-in-a-datasnap-server-me]

Comment: Send the token as bearer to each request. Validate the token on server side for every request by checking following points:
1. signature of token: Is token created by the right authority
2. Check the token expiry  time.: Do not allow to old tokens
3. Check the role or access level for the desired server service: Is the access for this user allowed?